# Shared memory bank conflicts, multicast and broadcast performance Cuda

Tags: cuda, multicast, broadcast

I understand that for Kepler devices (cc 3.0) and above shared memory conflicts occur only when threads from the same warp access different words in the same bank. If all threads access the same word (broadcast) or some threads access the same word (multicast) in a bank, there are no conflicts.

In the following code:

```
__shared__ float3 nodeCoefficient[sideX * sideY * sideZ];
```

...

```
for (unsigned int zIdx = 0; zIdx < 4; zIdx++) {
    for (unsigned int yIdx = 0; yIdx < 4; yIdx++) {
        for (unsigned int xIdx = 0; xIdx < 4; ++xIdx) {
            int indexXYZ = ((threadidx.z/5.5 + zIdx) * sideY + (threadidx.y/5.5+ yIdx)) * sideX + (threadidx.x/5.5 + xIdx);
            displace += nodeCoefficient[indexXYZ] * (bValues[xIdx].x * bValues[yIdx].y);
        }
    }
}
```

there is multicast in shared memory access

Now, if we change indexXYZ to:

```
indexXYZ = (( zIdx) * sideY + ( yIdx)) * sideX + ( xIdx);
```

we have broadcast.

Finally if we change indexXYZ to:

```
int indexXYZ = ((threadidx.z + zIdx) * sideY + (threadidx.y+ yIdx)) * sideX + (threadidx.x + xIdx);
```

We have a linear accessing pattern.

The performance comparison of the above including a deliberate bank conflict version is as follows on a gtx750m:

1.Multicast: 18 ms
2.Broadcast: 9 ms
3.Linear: 5.5ms
4.Bank conflict: 90ms

I would expect that bank conflict free code would behave similarly. Why are there differences between, broadcast, multicast and linear accessing?

Cheers,
T

(the question was subsequently edited, as the original version was down-marked as too broad)

Comment: If you're allowed to, it would be nice to write here the relevant passage

Comment: Take a look at [High Performance Computing for Engineering Applications](http://sbel.wisc.edu/Courses/ME964/2013/Lectures/lecture1007.pdf), in particular slide 16.

Comment: thanks, that is a very good and comprehensive guide

Answer (score 1):

If we have a shared memory definition like this:

```
__shared__ int sdata[BLOCK_SIZE*2];
```

The following line of code would generate the bank access pattern represented [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-5-x__examples-of-strided-shared-memory-accesses) (middle column) with no bank conflicts:

```
int a = sdata[2*(threadIdx.x%16)];
```

The following line of code would generate the same bank access pattern (albeit to different locations) with 2-way bank conflicts:

```
int a = sdata[2*threadIdx.x];
```

Comment: Thanks, both answers were really helpful. Just wondering, how can a bank conflict occur for a kepler device (capability 3.0)?

Comment: It occurs in essentially the same way as any other device.  Two or more threads are requesting data from different locations in shared memory that have the same bank.  There are many questions here on SO that explain and give examples of bank conflicts.  For the most part, Kepler behaves the same as Fermi, especially in 32-bit bank mode.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, they were really helpful